# DropDownList Value won't change

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

When I select any value from the DropDownList, the first one gets selected.

The code's purpose is whenever I choose a value from the DropDownList the corresponding value from the database should be displayed in the TextBox.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("connection string");
        con.Open();
        DataTable Seminars = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT SeminarName, ID  FROM SeminarData", con);
        adapter.Fill(Seminars);
        DropDownList1.DataSource = Seminars;
        DropDownList1.DataTextField = "SeminarName";
        DropDownList1.DataValueField = "SeminarName";
        DropDownList1.DataBind(); 
        con.Close();

    }

protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("connection string");
    con.Open();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT  SeminarNameE,TrainerName FROM SeminarData WHERE SeminarName='" + DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value +"'", con);
    SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);
    sqlDa.Fill(dt);

    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        TextBox1.Text = dt.Rows[0]["SeminarNameE"].ToString();
        TextBox2.Text = dt.Rows[0]["TrainerName"].ToString();
    }



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your page load with this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (!Page.IsPostBack) {
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("connection string");
    con.Open();
    DataTable Seminars = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT SeminarName, ID  FROM SeminarData", con);
    adapter.Fill(Seminars);
    DropDownList1.DataSource = Seminars;
    DropDownList1.DataTextField = "SeminarName";
    DropDownList1.DataValueField = "SeminarName";
    DropDownList1.DataBind(); 
    con.Close();
  }
}
```

It needs !Page.IsPostBack, because everytime you bind, you clear any selections.  In this code, it binds on every page load.  Adding !Page.IsPostback will ensure it binds only the first load.